# Getting to Azure Functions in an app service environment from Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

So,

I have an ASE in our company Azure subscription. The ASE has a VNET surrounding it as the ASE is on provisioned isolated infrastructure (I2) instance.

I have a resource group with this ASE in it and an Azure data factory instance. There is an Azure Function App Service in the ASE.

When I go to Azure data factory and put an Azure function activity in my pipeline and put in all the right details I get an error:

```
"errorCode": "3610",
"message": "There was an error while calling endpoint.",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Azure Function1",
"details": []
```

}

So basically my gut instinct is that because ADF is a public resource and does not sit within the VNET that the functions do, it cannot resolve the URL of my functions to anywhere.

I may be totally wrong about this, but if anyone has any idea what I could do to fix this, i'd love to hear your thoughts.

Cheers

G

Comment: I think you're right. Check if there's a service endpoint that you could use to allow de ADF access to your ASE

Comment: appreciate you coming back on this so quickly, i'll deffo have a look at configuring a service endpoint.

Comment: Hi, any progress on this problem? I tried to put the data factory function linked service in the self-hosted IR (in the same network as the ASE), but still got the same error.